# PHP redirect based on HTTP_USER_AGENT

Tags: php, html, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my page based on User Agent. I've written a piece of code and included it before `<!doctype html>`

```
$SAFARI_URL = "https://example.com/ms/";
$OPERA_URL = "https://example.com/ms/";
$OTHER_URL = "https://example.com/";
$CHROME_URL = "https://example.com/";
// Redirection code
$HTTP_USER_AGENT = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function str_present($str,$substr)
{
  $pos = strpos($str,$substr);

  if($pos === false) {
   return false;
  }else {
    return true;
  }
}

  if (str_present($HTTP_USER_AGENT, "Safari")){ 
    Header ("Location: " . $SAFARI_URL);
  }else if (str_present($HTTP_USER_AGENT, "Opera")){ 
    Header ("Location: " . $OPERA_URL);
  }else if (str_present($HTTP_USER_AGENT, "Chrome")){ 
    Header ("Location: " . $CHROME_URL);
  }else{ 
    Header ("Location: " . $OTHER_URL);
  }
```

The issue is that it's not working for Chrome. Am I doing something wrong? Is it not precise enough?

Comment: detecting user agent browser is not this easy. search to find better functions for that.

Comment: Have you seen `$HTTP_USER_AGENT`'s content? It may contain `Safari` (I've tested `navigator.userAgent` in Chrome console)

Comment: _“I'm trying to redirect my page based on User Agent.“_ - why, what would make that necessary? Treating every browser on its own was not a good approach 10 years ago, and it hasn’t become better since. What actual _problem_ are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: _“Am I doing something wrong?”_ - hard to say, if you did your basic debugging wrong, or didn’t do any at all … A debug output of what $HTTP_USER_AGENT actually contains reveals what the problem is in no time.

Comment: @misorude I've created a website that uses some modern properties like CSS Flexbox and 3D Transforms without a fallback. Why? Got a lot to learn I guess. That causes the website to not display at all on Safari or any other WebKit Browser. Until I fix that, I want that users visiting from safari are redirected to the old version of the website which works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this code to detect user's browsers.

```
 $SAFARI_URL = "https://example.com/ms/";
    $OPERA_URL = "https://example.com/ms/";
    $OTHER_URL = "https://example.com/";
    $CHROME_URL = "https://example.com/";
    $user_agent =    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if (strpos($user_agent, 'Opera') || strpos($user_agent, 'OPR/')) 
         redirect($OPERA_URL );
        elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Edge')) 
         //redirect($url);
        elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Chrome')) 
        redirect($CHROME_URL );
        elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Safari')) 
        redirect($SAFARI_URL );
        elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Firefox')) 
        //redirect($url);
        elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'MSIE') || strpos($user_agent, 'Trident/7'))  
        //redirect($url); //internet explorer

        redirect($OTHER_URL);
    }



function redirect($url) {
    ob_start();
    header('Location: '.$url);
    ob_end_flush();
    die();
}
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct because it does work. However, I found a more appropriate approach to this without using PHP.